# Detecting when a box is already with X or O in TIC TAC TOE

Tags: c#

New programmer here. I am trying to create the game tic tac toe, but I am stuck trying to see if the box has already an X or a O.

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System;
using System.CodeDom;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UdemyEjercicio21F
{
    internal class Program
    {

        // Create the Array
        string[,] positions = new string[3, 3]
        {
                {"1", "2", "3"},
                {"4", "5", "6"},
                {"7", "8", "9"}
        };
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // We create the methods 
            Program gameProgram = new Program();
            gameProgram.Game();
        }

        //Create the main method that is going to keep track of the game
        void Game()
        {
            // Print the board for the first time
            printBoard();

            // Create our both variables, the firs one to capture the answer of the player, the second one, the 2 players
            string answer;
            string player = "Player 1";

            // Create a bool variable to help me create the loop
            bool helpingBool = true;

            // We create the method that is going to change between Players.
            while (helpingBool)
            {
                // WINCONDITIO: We need to determinate 2 things, if one of the players gets 3 characters in a row, it wins the game.   
                if (positions[0, 0] == "O" && positions[0, 1] == "O" && positions[0, 2] == "O")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 1 has won the game");
                    Console.Read();
                }
                else
                {
                    // First we ask to the default player, "Player 1"
                    // This method returns the variable answer
                    ask();
                    // Once I have this variable, I can use it with my other methods to change the Board

                    // Use If to see if we are playing as player 1 or 2 and change the Board
                    // This methods needs answer to work, but I have it as ask() returns it
                    if (player == "Player 2")
                    {
                        PlayerX();
                        player = "Player 1";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        PlayerO();
                        player = "Player 2";
                    }

                    // After the Board has changed, I print the result.
                    printBoard();

                    // And as NO WIN CONDITIONS are defined, the loop keeps asking.
                }


            }


            // This method ask for an answer, if the answer is "wrong", keeps going. Returns answer
            string ask()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}, please, what box do you want to use", player);
                    answer = Console.ReadLine();

                    //Control Variables
                    string stringToCheckX = "X";
                    string stringToCheckO = "O";
                    bool track = false;


                    for (int helpX = 0; helpX < positions.GetLength(0); helpX++)
                    {
                        for (int helpY = 0; helpY < positions.GetLength(1); helpY++)
                        {
                            // If the answer is X, 
                            if (positions[helpX, helpY] == stringToCheckX)
                            {
                                track = true;
                                Console.WriteLine("We have detected X");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if(!track)
                    {
                        if (int.TryParse(answer, out int answerInt))
                        {
                            if (answerInt >= 1 && answerInt < 10)
                            {
                                return answer;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("C) The answer introduced is a int , not a box");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            track = false;
                            Console.WriteLine("B) The answer introduced is a string, not a box");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("A) X has been detected, please select a different box.");
                    }
                }
            }
            // This metod changes the Board to draw a 0. Needs answer.
            void PlayerO()
        {
            switch (answer)
            {
                case "1":
                    positions[0, 0] = "O";
                    break;
                case "2":
                    positions[0, 1] = "O";
                    break;
                case "3":
                    positions[0, 2] = "O";
                    break;
                case "4":
                    positions[1, 0] = "O";
                    break;
                case "5":
                    positions[1, 1] = "O";
                    break;
                case "6":
                    positions[1, 2] = "O";
                    break;
                case "7":
                    positions[2, 0] = "O";
                    break;
                case "8":
                    positions[2, 1] = "O";
                    break;
                case "9":
                    positions[2, 2] = "O";
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Please introduce a valid answer");
                    break;
            }
        }
            // This metod changes the Board to draw a X. Needs answer.
            void PlayerX()
            {
                switch (answer)
                {
                    case "1":
                        positions[0, 0] = "X";
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        positions[0, 1] = "X";
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        positions[0, 2] = "X";
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        positions[1, 0] = "X";
                        break;
                    case "5":
                        positions[1, 1] = "X";
                        break;
                    case "6":
                        positions[1, 2] = "X";
                        break;
                    case "7":
                        positions[2, 0] = "X";
                        break;
                    case "8":
                        positions[2, 1] = "X";
                        break;
                    case "9":
                        positions[2, 2] = "X";
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Please introduce a valid answer");
                        break;
                }
            }
            // Print Board Method
            void printBoard()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}  |  {1}  |  {2}", positions[0, 0], positions[0, 1], positions[0, 2]);
                Console.WriteLine("-------------");
                Console.WriteLine("{0}  |  {1}  |  {2}", positions[1, 0], positions[1, 1], positions[1, 2]);
                Console.WriteLine("-------------");
                Console.WriteLine("{0}  |  {1}  |  {2}", positions[2, 0], positions[2, 1], positions[2, 2]);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code.

The main problem is that I can detect if the answer is not one of the boxes, but the moment I input an X(for example), I get stuck as I can only detect if the X is somewhere else in the Array.

I have tried to use an Switch with the answer or to separate the search with a external method, but I cannot grasp the solution. I can create the array and the win method is already defined.

But right now, If I input 3, I get an O; If I then input a 2, I get an X. And the program get stuck as they see an X already in place. If I disable the check, then the players can use each other boxes.

What I desire to get is that If in this case, Players 2 inputs again 3, the box is already used.

What I am missing?

Thanks,

EDIT: I have tried CHATGPT too, but I cannot explain properly what i want to achieve.

If I use something like this, I can finish the game but for stepping in each other boxes.

```
            string ask()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Ask(); 

                CheckAlreadyX();
                if (encontradoX)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("A) The answer introduced is already an answer");
                }
                else if (int.TryParse(answer, out int answerInt))
                {
                    if (answerInt >= 1 && answerInt < 10)
                    {
                        return answer;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("B) The answer introduced is a really big int , not a box");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("C) The answer introduced is a string, not a box");
                }
            }
        }

        void Ask()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, please, what box do you want to use", player);
            answer = Console.ReadLine();
        }




        void CheckAlreadyX () 
        {
            string stringToCheckX = "X";
            for (int helpX = 0; helpX < positions.GetLength(0); helpX++)
            {
                for (int helpY = 0; helpY < positions.GetLength(1); helpY++)
                {
                    if (positions[helpX, helpY] == stringToCheckX)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("We have detected X");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

EDIT 2:

Thanks a lot! I have completed the tictactoe game.

I could still improve the part where the game finished, and I am pretty sure that checking the win condition could be done with less code, but being this one of my first exercise, I think is pretty fine. My final code is this one, taking the feedback into account and trying to mix it with my understanding of C#.

```
namespace UdemyEjercicio21M
{
    internal class Program
    {
        // Create the Array
        string[,] positions = new string[3, 3]
        {
                {"1", "2", "3"},
                {"4", "5", "6"},
                {"7", "8", "9"}
        };
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // We create the methods 
            Program gameProgram = new Program();
            gameProgram.Game();
        }

        //Create the main method that is going to keep track of the game
        void Game()
        {
            // Print the board for the first time
            printBoard();

            // Create our both variables, the first one to capture the answer of the player, the second one, the 2 players
            string answer;
            string player = "Player 1";

            // Create a loop, if they reach turn 9 the game resets, as there are not a winner
            // This part could be improved to send a final menssage
            
            for (int turn = 0; turn < 9; turn++)
            {
                //Check if a player wins the game. Brute forced it.
                WinCondition();
                if (player == "Player 2")
                {
                    //The variable answer is the returned value of the method. 
                    answer = ask();
                    PlayerX();
                    player = "Player 1";
                    printBoard();
                }
                else
                {
                    answer = ask();
                    PlayerO();
                    player = "Player 2";
                    printBoard();
                }
            }


            // This method ask for an answer, if the answer is "wrong", keeps going. Returns returnedAnswer.
            string ask()
            {
                int y = 0, x = 0;
                bool validPos = false;
                string returnedAnswer = null;

                while (!validPos)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0}, please, what box do you want to use? Box: ", player);
                    answer = Console.ReadLine();
                    int pos;

                    // Parse the answer to an int.
                    if (int.TryParse(answer, out pos))
                    {
                        // if the parsed int is betweern 1 and 9, we create coordenates to the array.
                        if (pos >= 1 && pos <= 9)
                        {
                            // The coordenates
                            y = (pos - 1) / 3; // integer division
                            x = (pos - 1) % 3; // modulus

                            // If the positions do not have an X or an O, we return a positive and an answer.
                            if (positions[y, x] != "X" && positions[y, x] != "O")
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("{0}, y es igual a {1} y x es igual a {2}", positions[y, x], y, x);
                                validPos = true;
                                returnedAnswer = answer;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("That box is already taken!");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Box must be >=1 and <=9 !");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Position!");
                    }
                }
                return returnedAnswer;
            }
            // This method checks every posibility to see if we win.
            void WinCondition()
            {
                if (positions[0, 0] == "O" && positions[0, 1] == "O" && positions[0, 2] == "O")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 1 has won the game");
                    Console.Read();
                }
                else if (positions[1, 0] == "O" && positions[1, 1] == "O" && positions[1, 2] == "O")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 1 has won the game");
                    Console.Read();
                }
                else if (positions[2, 0] == "O" && positions[2, 1] == "O" && positions[2, 2] == "O")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 1 has won the game");
                    Console.Read();
                }
                else if (positions[0, 0] == "O" && positions[1, 1] == "O" && positions[2, 2] == "O")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 1 has won the game");
                    Console.Read();
                }
                else if (positions[0, 2] == "O" && positions[1, 1] == "O" && positions[2, 0] == "O")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 1 has won the game");
                    Console.Read();
                }
                else if (positions[0, 0] == "O" && positions[1, 0] == "O" && positions[2, 0] == "O")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 1 has won the game");
                    Console.Read();
                }
                else if (positions[0, 1] == "O" && positions[1, 1] == "O" && positions[2, 1] == "O")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 1 has won the game");
                    Console.Read();
                }
                else if (positions[0, 2] == "O" && positions[1, 2] == "O" && positions[2, 2] == "O")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 1 has won the game");
                    Console.Read();
                }
                //
                if (positions[0, 0] == "X" && positions[0, 1] == "X" && positions[0, 2] == "X")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 2 has won the game");
                    Console.Read();
                }
                else if (positions[1, 0] == "X" && positions[1, 1] == "X" && positions[1, 2] == "X")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 2 has won the game");
                    Console.Read();
                }
                else if (positions[2, 0] == "X" && positions[2, 1] == "X" && positions[2, 2] == "X")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 2 has won the game");
                    Console.Read();
                }
                else if (positions[0, 0] == "X" && positions[1, 1] == "X" && positions[2, 2] == "X")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 2 has won the game");
                    Console.Read();
                }
                else if (positions[0, 2] == "X" && positions[1, 1] == "X" && positions[2, 0] == "X")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 2 has won the game");
                    Console.Read();
                }
                else if (positions[0, 0] == "X" && positions[1, 0] == "X" && positions[2, 0] == "X")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 2 has won the game");
                    Console.Read();
                }
                else if (positions[0, 1] == "X" && positions[1, 1] == "X" && positions[2, 1] == "X")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 2 has won the game");
                    Console.Read();
                }
                else if (positions[0, 2] == "X" && positions[1, 2] == "X" && positions[2, 2] == "X")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 2 has won the game");
                    Console.Read();
                }
            }
            //This method changes the Board to draw a 0. Needs answer.
            void PlayerO()
            {
                switch (answer)
                {
                    case "1":
                        positions[0, 0] = "O";
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        positions[0, 1] = "O";
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        positions[0, 2] = "O";
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        positions[1, 0] = "O";
                        break;
                    case "5":
                        positions[1, 1] = "O";
                        break;
                    case "6":
                        positions[1, 2] = "O";
                        break;
                    case "7":
                        positions[2, 0] = "O";
                        break;
                    case "8":
                        positions[2, 1] = "O";
                        break;
                    case "9":
                        positions[2, 2] = "O";
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Please introduce a valid answer");
                        break;
                }
            }
            // This method changes the Board to draw a X. Needs answer.
            void PlayerX()
            {
                switch (answer)
                {
                    case "1":
                        positions[0, 0] = "X";
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        positions[0, 1] = "X";
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        positions[0, 2] = "X";
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        positions[1, 0] = "X";
                        break;
                    case "5":
                        positions[1, 1] = "X";
                        break;
                    case "6":
                        positions[1, 2] = "X";
                        break;
                    case "7":
                        positions[2, 0] = "X";
                        break;
                    case "8":
                        positions[2, 1] = "X";
                        break;
                    case "9":
                        positions[2, 2] = "X";
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Please introduce a valid answer");
                        break;
                }
            }
            // Print Board Method
            void printBoard()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}  |  {1}  |  {2}", positions[0, 0], positions[0, 1], positions[0, 2]);
                Console.WriteLine("-------------");
                Console.WriteLine("{0}  |  {1}  |  {2}", positions[1, 0], positions[1, 1], positions[1, 2]);
                Console.WriteLine("-------------");
                Console.WriteLine("{0}  |  {1}  |  {2}", positions[2, 0], positions[2, 1], positions[2, 2]);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep track of _available_ moves and only present those as options to the player. Then remove the one the player chose. Until there is a winner or no more moves available.

Comment: Clever way to see the problem. I will try it. Thanks @Fildor

Comment: Trying my best at debuging (using comments) and getting help. Thanks @GHDevOps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply A LOT using code like below.

It converts the integer version of their answer to the correct `y` and `x` co-ordinates using integer division and the modulus operator.

This also simplifies setting the player character at the selected position:

```
    void Game()
    {
        String answer;
        String player = "Player 1";

        while (true) // really should be: while (!gameOver)
        {
            printBoard();

            int y=0, x=0;
            Boolean validPos = false;
            while (!validPos)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}, please, what box do you want to use? Box: ", player);
                answer = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
                int pos;
                if (int.TryParse(answer, out pos))
                {
                    if (pos >= 1 && pos <= 9)
                    {
                        y = (pos - 1) / 3; // integer division
                        x = (pos - 1) % 3; // modulus

                        if (positions[y, x] != "X" && positions[y, x] != "O")
                        {
                            validPos = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("That box is already taken!");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Box must be >=1 and <=9 !");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Position!");
                }
            }

            takeBox(y, x, (player == "Player 1") ? "O" : "X"); // Player 1 = "O", Player 2 = "X"

            // ... check for a win condition? ...

            // swap players
            player = (player == "Player 1") ? "Player 2" : "Player 1";
        }
    }

    void takeBox(int y, int x, String playerChar)
    {
        positions[y, x] = playerChar;
    }
```

Comment: This was clever. Thanks a lot for the input. I have finished the exercise.